# Проблема с combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Доброе время суток.

Я добавил себе стиль для `Scrollviewer` и он работает отлично.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что когда я открываю `Combobox` , мне появляется `Scrollviewer`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожайлуста как убрать этот `Scrollviewer` из `Combobox`.

Код стиля для `Scrollviewer` :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" 
                Value="visible" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" 
                Value="visible"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ScrollContentPresenter 
                                x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ScrollBar 
                                x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Minimum="0.0"
                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay}"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"         
                                Cursor="Hand"
                                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar"/>
                            <ScrollBar 
                                x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Minimum="0"
                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay}"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                Cursor="Hand"
                                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" 
                 Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="true">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
                    Value="visible"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
                    Value="visible"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph" Value="UpArrow">
                            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 3,0 l 3,8 l -6,0 Z"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph" Value="DownArrow">
                            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0,0 l 6,0 l -3,8 Z"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph" Value="LeftArrow">
                            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0,3 l 8,-3 l 0,6 Z"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph" Value="RightArrow">
                            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0,0 l 8,3 l -8,3 Z"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb"
       TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border Background="#FF777777" CornerRadius="2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="HorizontalScrollBarPageButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                           Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                           Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="VerticalScrollBarPageButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                           Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                           Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="#BCBABE"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="-2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Border 
                        x:Name="Bg"
                        CornerRadius="2"                         
                        Margin="2"
                        Opacity="0.75"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Grid
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RepeatButton
                                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}"
                                Background="White"                                    
                                IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"
                                theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="UpArrow"
                                Margin="0,4"/>
                            <RepeatButton                   
                                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}"
                                Background="White"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}"
                                theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="DownArrow"
                                Margin="0,4">
                            </RepeatButton>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bg"
                                Property="Visibility"
                                Value="visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Width"
                        Value="5"/>
                    <Setter
                        Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                                <Border 
                                    CornerRadius="4"                         
                                    Margin="2"
                                    Opacity="0.75"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Grid
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                                            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Track
                                            Name="PART_Track"
                                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                            IsDirectionReversed="true">
                                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarPageButton}"
                                                    Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}"/>
                                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarPageButton}"
                                                    Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}"/>
                                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                            <Track.Thumb>
                                                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"
                                                    theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="VerticalGripper"
                                                    Margin="2"/>
                                            </Track.Thumb>
                                        </Track>
                                        <RepeatButton
                                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}"
                                            Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                            Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"
                                            theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="UpArrow"
                                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                                            <RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            </RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
                                        </RepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton                           
                                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}"
                                            Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                                            Grid.Row="2"
                                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                            Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}"
                                            theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="DownArrow"
                                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                                            <RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            </RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
                                        </RepeatButton>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Width"
                        Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                        Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                                <Border 
                                    x:Name="Bg"
                                    CornerRadius="2"                         
                                    Margin="2"
                                    Opacity="0.75"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                    <Grid
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <RepeatButton
                                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}"    
                                            Background="White"
                                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                            Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}"
                                            theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="LeftArrow"
                                            Margin="4,0"/>
                                        <RepeatButton
                                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}"                                        
                                            Background="White"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                            Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}"
                                            theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="RightArrow"
                                            Margin="4,0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                         Value="false">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Bg"
                                            Property="Visibility"
                                            Value="visible"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Width"
                        Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                        Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height"
                        Value="5"/>
                    <Setter
                        Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                                <Border 
                                    CornerRadius="4"                         
                                    Margin="2"
                                    Opacity="0.75"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Grid
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Track
                                            Name="PART_Track"
                                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBarPageButton}"
                                                  Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand}"/>
                                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBarPageButton}"
                                                  Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageRightCommand}"/>
                                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                            <Track.Thumb>
                                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"
                                                   theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="HorizontalGripper"
                                                   Margin="2"/>
                                            </Track.Thumb>
                                        </Track>
                                        <RepeatButton
                                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}"
                                            Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                            Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}"
                                            theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="LeftArrow"
                                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                                            <RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            </RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
                                        </RepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton                           
                                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}"
                                            Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                                            Grid.Column="2"
                                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                            Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}"
                                            theme:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="RightArrow"
                                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                                            <RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            </RepeatButton.RenderTransform>
                                        </RepeatButton>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Код `Combobox`:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="Combox_Client"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="20,43,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="230"
                  IsEditable="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  SelectionChanged="Combox_Client_SelectionChanged"  >
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="NameItem" IsSelected="True"   >
                Select Client
            </ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

Прошу вас помочь решить эту проблему.

Спасибо!

Comment: `<ComboBox ... ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">`

Comment: Ну или убрать из стиля `<Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility".../>` `<Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility".../>`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Я решил пробему , сделал все value = disable 

`<Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" 
                Value="disable" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" 
                Value="disable"/>`

И для каждый `ScrollViewer` сделал :

`HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">`